# Command line arguments reading monad library

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments

I'm looking for a library which uses a monad to abstract over the fuss of command line arguments parsing and help generation. I have the following fairly obvious usage pattern in mind:

```
main = do
  portOrSocket <- Args.run $ do
    mbSocket <- Args.read $ Args.Arg "s" "socket" "Description"
    mbPort <- Args.read $ Args.Arg "p" "port" "Description"
    case mbSocket of
      Just socket -> return $ Right socket
      Nothing -> case mbPort of
        Just port -> return $ Left port
        Nothing -> return $ Left defaultPort
  ...
```

The above code has all the information needed to handle parsing, validation and usage generation and IMO is fairly easy to comprehend. Unfortunately after looking thru hackage and checking out packages like cmdargs, cmdlib, parseargs, ReadArgs I haven't found anything anywhere close to this. But before diving into implementation I'd like to ensure that I haven't missed anything. So is there a library that exploits a similar approach to the problem?

Comment: Have you tried `optparse-applicative`?

Comment: +1 for `optparse-applicative`.  It's great.

Comment: It seems that it would be almost impossible to generate automatic help messages, if parameters depended on values of other parameters. This is probably why _optparse-applicative_ uses Applicative.

Comment: @PetrPudlák Yes. After actually trying to implement this I came to the same conclusion. Looks like it needs to be an Arrow, which _optparse-applicative_ seemingly already has.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Thanks! Looks like the only candidate. Do you mind posting it as an answer showcasing how you would solve the presented problem using this library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `optparse-applicative`.  The most common use pattern looks like this (I'm just copy-and-pasting from a small utility I use):

```
options :: Parser (String, String)
options = (,)
    <$> (strOption $ mconcat [
        short 'n',
        long "node",
        metavar "NODE",
        value "127.0.0.1",
        showDefaultWith id,
        completer (bashCompleter "hostname"),
        help "AMQP node to connect to" ] )
    <*> (strOption $ mconcat [
        short 'q',
        long "queue",
        metavar "QUEUE",
        value "1.0.0",
        showDefaultWith id,
        help "Queue to initialize" ] )

main = do
    (hostName, queue) <-
        execParser $ info (helper <*> options) $ mconcat [
            fullDesc,
            header "The Suns setup utility",
            progDesc "Sets up an AMQP node",
            footer "Report bugs to Gabriel439@gmail.com" ]
    ...
```

When I run the compiled program with `-h`, I get:

```
$ suns-admin -h
The Suns setup utility

Usage: suns-admin [-n|--node NODE] [-q|--queue QUEUE]
  Sets up an AMQP node

Available options:
  -h,--help                Show this help text
  -n,--node NODE           AMQP node to connect to (default: 127.0.0.1)
  -q,--queue QUEUE         Queue to initialize (default: 1.0.0)

Report bugs to Gabriel439@gmail.com
```

That gives you some idea of some nifty options that you can play with and the nice output that the program generates.

Answer (score 2):

If anybody's interested in solving the problem presented in the question using `optparse-applicative`, here's how I achieved that:

```
import Options.Applicative

getOptions :: Int -> IO (Either Int String)
getOptions defaultPort = 
  execParser $ 
  info (helper <*> parser defaultPort) $
    fullDesc <>
    progDesc "Run a content-db server on a socket or a port" <>
    header "Run a content-db server" 

parser :: Int -> Parser (Either Int String)
parser defaultPort = 
  portOrSocket <$> 
    (optional . strOption)
      ( short 's' <>
        long "socket" <>
        help "Socket" )
    <*>
    option
      ( short 'p' <>
        long "port" <>
        help "Port" <>
        value defaultPort )
  where
    portOrSocket (Just socket) _ = Right socket
    portOrSocket _ port = Left port

main = do
  getOptions 43400 >>= \o -> case o of
    Left port -> print port
    Right socket -> print socket
```